# Getting the error in Media.Type despite importing the class not getting the suggestion as well

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jakarta-ee

Getting the error in `Media.Type`

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType ;

@Path("/Hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML) //error
    public String sayHello() {
        String resource = "<?xml version = '1.0' ?>" + " <Hello>Hi There ,this sumit from XML </Hello>";
        return resource;
    }
}
```

[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiZlp.jpg)

Comment: import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Hello")
public class Hello {
 
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
 public String sayHello()
 {
  String resource="<?xml version = '1.0' ?>" +
    " <Hello>Hi There ,this sumit from XML </Hello>";
  return resource;
 }

Comment: You're likely missing the required jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

"`import javax.ws.rs.Produces;`"

instead of :

"`import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;`"

It resolved in my machine